# Javascript file not reaching check point. Possibly not loading.

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code:

```
var serverRequest = function(){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/6ZHYW8/messages', true);
request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
document.write('2');
}, false);
request.send(null);
}

/******************Functions *************************/
serverRequest();

/********************* Runtime Code ********************************/
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    start();
}, false);
```

While using google-chrome,

```
http://localhost:8080/6ZHYW8/messages
```

responds with:

```
[
  {
    "nickname": "\"Administrator\"",
    "message": "\"KEEP IT CLEAN. You crazy kids\""
  },
  {
    "nickname": "vanilla",
    "message": "THUNDA"
  }

]
```

Would anyone happen to know why my code never reaches "document.write('2')"?

Answer (score 0):

Because `request.addEventListener('load')` is not valid. You need to use the `request.onreadstatechange` method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/readystatechange